# 503 error or slow page load however the site is too fast and page optimized

Tags: wordpress, performance, http-status-code-503

I have a wordpress site on which there are many plugins but I have optimized them in a way that plugins are loaded on specific page. Also I have optimized the page speed of the site to the highest as I could.
The hosting is really great which supports at least 200 online users. so there is nothing wrong with the hosting even I have checked the resources use of the host even it does not get above 20% use of the resources.
the website caching is too strong in my own country the page speed is less than 1 second. but sometimes it it too slow too load. sometimes it shows 503 error. but most of the time even it does not show 503 error just too slow to load the pages not always 50% 50%.
50% of the time does not have any problems but 50% of the time it gets slow seems there is a conflict.
2 percent it shows 503 error but the problem is not the hosting resources.
[this picture shows there is nothing wrong with the host resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBSGV.png)

So what I did was as follow:

1. disable all the plugins and one by one I activated them to check which one has a problem. Almost it gets a little bit better but the problem still exist. now I do not see 503 error anymore but slow loading keeps ​going on.
2. I have changed the theme to twenty twenty the default of wordpress. the problem still exists.
3. I kept wp-content and wp-config and reuploaded a fresh wordpress. the problem still exists.
4. I have have deleted cache file and htaccess file completely and made new fresh one the problem exists
   I do not know what I have to do next to solve the problem.
   I wonder if anyone can help me in this case? I would appreciate it if you could help me to solve this problem.
   how can I get read of this conflict.
   p.s I have changed the php version as well

Comment: Did you checked using your browser's Developer Tools to see if there's any assets taking time to load? Do you see any errors in the Console (in your browser window)? Are there any websites in the same server other than yours? Did you tried installing a fresh WordPress installation on a subdomain or something and tested it? Did you enabled error logging, if so can you please check whether there's any errors appearing in the log?

Comment: hi I have checked the console there is nothing wrong.
this is the only website on the host.
I have to check error logging now. thank you so much